# How to set the NumberFormatException as label

Tags: java, exception

So I have two boxes where you type in your numbers, and when clicked, it divides number one by number two and sets the label with the answer. (In a perfect world.)

However, you can also write down a word.. 
I got this for that:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
      // the String to int conversion happens here
      numberOne = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText().trim());

      // print out the value after the conversion
      System.out.println("int i = " + jTextField1);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      System.out.println(nfe.getMessage() + " is not a number... ");

    }
    //numberOne = Integer.jTextField1
    answer = calc.calculateNumbers(numberOne,numberTwo);
    jLabel1.setText(answer);
}
```

Now instead of getting the error message in the console, I want the label (of the answer) to be set as message.

So, something like: jLabel.setText(*ERROR MESSAGE*)
but when I put it in the catch, I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the code you are trying because it should work?  Note: if you call `setText` more than once you only see the last value set of course.  If it still doesn't make sense I suggest you step through your code in your debugger.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Read my answer! Apparently I overrode my setText with a blank one, thinking It didn't set it in the first place. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to avoid catching the Exception too early and pretending it didn't happen.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String text = jTextField1.getText().trim();
    try {
      // the String to int conversion happens here
      int numberOne = Integer.parseInt(text);

      String answer = calc.calculateNumbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
      jLabel1.setText(answer);

    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      jLabel1.setText(text + " is not an integer... ");
    }
}
```

Try to place the catch after the code which you can't run if the exception occurs. Also avoid using fields when you could use local variables.

Comment: I'd like to request a small tweak on this, the nfe.getMessage() returns "For input string: '<input>' ", could I ONLY get the input without the "for input string" part?

Comment: @Paramone BTW it will reject `1.0` which is a number but not an integer.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. And indeed, I changed the Integers to Doubles as it makes way more sense. (Completely forgot)..

Answer (score 0):

Reading @Peter Lawrey's comment, I realized I did

```
jLabel1.setText();
```

twice..

Looking like this:

```
catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      System.out.println(nfe.getMessage() + "is not a number... ");
      jLabel1.setText(nfe.getMessage());
    }
    answer = calc.calculateNumbers(numberOne,numberTwo);
    jLabel1.setText(answer);
```

Apparently I COULD set the jLabel's text to something, but I overrode it with the second .setText();..

Thank you guys however!